# whether i have to choose classification or clustering for my project?

Tags: cluster-analysis, classification, eigenvector, euclidean-distance

I just detected faces using Viola-jones algorithm. I cropped faces from frames(or video)and I made it as training set.In my video there are 5 different faces. I decided to use eigenfaces for face recognition.I ended with finding eucledian distance for a input image.What Iam supposed do now.Whether I have to use classification or clustering technique?In my project they told to use kmeans clustering.How it can be done using eucledian distance explain?Give some useful links so that I can understand in better way.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 5 different faces, this sounds like classification to me. That is a label column!

I don't think k-means will get you anywhere. When you have high-dimensional data (such as images), k-means performs as good as random convex partitioning. I.e. it's largely useless.